# Limitar quantidade de dígitos na entrada de dados

Tags: c, validação

Estou com uma dificuldade para entender a questão de limitar caracteres, pesquisei, mas não compreendi muito bem como utilizar no código, eu fiz aqui o esboço, para entender mais ou menos o que quero, sei que não está certo o `if(tamanho<=4)`, fiz só para pegar a ideia, pois quero que o usuário digite somente 4 dígitos ou menos, poderiam dar essa força?

```
int main(){
    int tamanho, cargo;

    printf("1-operador");
    printf("2-operador");

    printf("Digite o numero do cargo");        

    switch(cargo){
        case 1:
            printf("Digite seu codigo de acesso");
            scanf("%d", &codigo);
            if(tamanho<=4){
                if(codigo==1234){
                    printf("joao carlos");
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: Se a variável é do tipo inteiro então se `(num < 10000)` a variável num tem no máximo 4 algarismos significativos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há um erro conceitual aí. Você está pedindo uma senha, uma informação descritiva, então ela deve ser uma *string* e não um número. Você poderia até validar para só ter dígitos numéricos, mas só porque esses são os caracteres aceitos não deve usar um tipo numérico. Tipos numéricos servem para fazer contas, não é o que deseja aí.

Se ainda for insistir no erro, se está pedindo para a pessoa digitar a senha e verificar se está certa, então não precisa verificar o tamanho, se a pessoa digitar a senha com tamanho errado a senha certamente está errada, não é relevante o tamanho. Se digitar a senha certa então o tamanho estará certo.

Isso faria sentido se estivesse pedindo para a pessoa digitar uma senha que ela iria usar a partir dali, aí você faz uma validação. Reforço que a validação não deveria ser tão simples e que deveria ser como uma *string*, mas se insistir no número e precisar fazer uma validação (em geral senha deveria aceitar tudo) então ela deveria ser se o valor é menor que 10000, porque certamente terá 4 dígitos (9999) ou menos, o que é estranho, nunca vi uma senha ser validada para ser menor que um tamanho, em geral valida se ela tem um tamanho mínimo, que mais uma vez mostra como é ruim usar um número. Mas note que só estou falando para completeza de raciocínio, não serve para esse seu código, ele não precisa fazer essa validação.

Nem entrei no mérito de colocar uma senha no código, porque entendo que isso é circunstancial para um exercício que importa outras coisas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ah sim, entendi, é sou novo em programação, obrigado pela dica, entendi agora.